# Movie Filter using jQuery and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a JavaScript filter that will sort movies, similar to the set up that you might see on amazon.com and so forth.

Using php/Laravel on the back end, I'm generating a series of div's that each contain a movie.  When the user clicks a checkbox (for example, with a movie genre), all movies that are not of that selected genre will removed.

I'm using this as a project to teach myself laravel, jquery, and vue.js, but the front end JavaScript work has me stumped and I could really use some help.  Thanks in advance.

Html/Php for checkboxes:

```
@foreach( $genres as $genre )
    <label class="form-check"> 
        <input class="form-check-input" id="genre" value="{{ $genre }}" type="checkbox" v-model="checked" @click="genreSearch()">
        <span class="form-check-label">{{ $genre }}</span>
    </label>
@endforeach 
<span>You've Checked: @{{ checked }} </span>
```

Html/Php for Movies

```
                 @foreach ($movies as $movie)           
                    <div class="card mb-2 {{ $movie->genre }}" id="{{ $movie->genre }}">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col-auto">
                                <a href="/movies/{{ $movie->id }}"><img src="{{ $movie->url }}" class="img-fluid" width="300px" height="100px" style="height: 400px;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card-block px-2">
                                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0"><strong>{{ $movie->title }}</strong></h5>
                                    @php $rating = $movie->rating->avg('rating'); @endphp

                                    @foreach(range( 1,5 ) as $i )
                                        <span class="fa-stack" style="width: 1em;">
                                            <i class="far fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                            @if( $rating > 0 )
                                                @if( $rating > 0.5 )
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star starred fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                                @else
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star-half fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                                @endif
                                            @endif
                                            @php $rating--; @endphp
                                        </span>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mt-2 mb-2 text-muted">By: {{ $movie->publisher }}</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Released: {{ $movie->released }}</h6>
                                    <p>{{ $movie->description }}</p>
                                    <div class="row ml-0">
                                        <a href="/movies/{{ $movie->id }}" class="badge badge-primary pt-2 pb-2 px-3 mr-2">Details</a>
                                        <a href="/movies/{{ $movie->id }}/ratings" class="badge badge-primary pt-2 pb-2 px-1 mr-2">Ratings &nbsp
                                            <span class="badge-light px-1">{{ $movie->rating->count() }}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>    
    var genreFilter = new Vue({
        el: '#genres',
        data: {
            checked: []
        },
        methods: {
            genreSearch: function () {
                $( "#Fantasy" ).toggle(function() {
                    alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
                }, function() {
                    alert( "Second Handler for toggle().called." );
                });

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First issue: your creating a new toggle binding every time an element is clicked.  That is going to create duplicate bindings.  Don't do that.  Second issue: do not use jQuery to change your view if you are using vue to build it.  Use vue to change it.  Changing the view with external logic causes it to become out of sync with the view data vue uses and you run the fairly high risk of vue overlaying your changes when it has to redraw.

Comment: Third issue: if the `#Fantasy` is meant to target `id="{{ $movie->genre }}"` and the genre can be the same on multiple movies, which seems to be a safe assumption, then you are generating non-web standard html by repeating ids.  Ids are expected to be unique per page.

Comment: @Taplar Yes the `#Fantasy` is a placeholder for my trying to get it to work with a single genre before I expand it to all the possible genres.  It will/should be `.Fantasy`

Comment: May i add to this that there currently is no Vue code in this question so I would remove the tag. Secondly, jQuery in combination with Vue is not the nicest thing in the world and I'd recommend to choose one of the two. jQuery mainly is a DOM and CSS manipulator, and it does not compare to a framework like Vue which is used for Single Page Applications/components. Its too much to explain here.